# Wrapping a react webapp in a web component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, web-component

I have a react webapp I would like to put into a web component. The webapp relies on a css and a sass file loaded by `import` statement. Of course moving the webapp into the web component causes styles to stop work because of shadow dom. I read a bunch of SO questions/answers and articles but I can't get how to apply .css and .scss files to the component. What I tried so far:

- load .css and .scss files as string by using `raw-loader` or `css-to-string-loader`  overriding react's webpack config by `react-app-rewired` and/or directly using syntax like `... = require('!css-to-string-loader!css-loader!./css/index.css');` (which always give compilation errors),
- load .css and .scss by using `styled-components` inspired by this [article](https://www.wpeform.io/blog/render-react-app-shadow-dom-styled-components/),
- trying to figure out how to add .css and .scss files to manifest.json to use the urls into web component's style elements.

This is how my web component looks right now:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const initparams = [ ... /*not relevant to question */ ];

class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = document.getElementById('app_mountpoint').attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    const style1 = document.createElement('style');
    style1.innerHTML = require('./css/index.css');
    const style2 = document.createElement('style');
    style2.innerHTML = ( './css/index-sass.scss');
    const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style1);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style2);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);

    ReactDOM.render(<App initparams={initparams} />, mountPoint);
  }
}
customElements.define('my-web-commponent', MyWebComponent);
```

My aim is to load the two files and add as inner HTML to a `style` element added to the shadow dom. Don't want to 'eject' that react webapp as possible. What am I doing wrong?